# merge statement using a cte throwing an error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to convert a MSSQL Query into Snowflake and I'm getting tripped up when I'm attempting to update my table using a secondary CTE after applying some business logic.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test
(
  id  integer,
  src text,
  val text

);
INSERT INTO test

SELECT t.*
FROM (
  VALUES (1, 'A', 'AA')
       , (1, 'A', 'AB') t(id, src, val)
  )
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM TEST

+--+---+---+
|ID|SRC|VAL|
+--+---+---+
|1 |A  |AA |
|1 |A  |AB |
+--+---+---+
```

---

```
WITH dat AS (
  SELECT id, src, val
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM test
              )

, src AS (
  SELECT id, src, val,
         MD5(
           ARRAY_TO_STRING(
             ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,src,val), ':'
             )
           ) AS CHANGE_HASH
  FROM dat
  WHERE rn = 1
           )

MERGE INTO target as tgt using src -- <-- this throws an error 
  ON src.id = tgt.id 
  AND src.CHANGE_HASH != tgt.CHANGE_HASH
THEN UPDATE 
SET (
  ...
       )
```

the error I get is

```
[42000][1003] SQL compilation error: syntax error line 61 at position 15 unexpected '<EOF>'.
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTE should be in the subquery like this:

```
MERGE INTO target as tgt using
(
  WITH dat AS (
  SELECT id, src, val
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM test)
, src AS (
  SELECT id, src, val,
         MD5(
           ARRAY_TO_STRING(
             ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,src,val), ':'
             )
           ) AS CHANGE_HASH
  FROM dat
  WHERE rn = 1 )
select * from src) src
  ON src.id = tgt.id 
  AND src.CHANGE_HASH != tgt.CHANGE_HASH
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.src = src.src;
```

Comment: damn, knew I was close, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The CTE is no needed as the entire section could be simplified with single [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html):

```
SELECT id, src, val,
         MD5(
           ARRAY_TO_STRING(
             ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,src,val), ':'
             )
           ) AS CHANGE_HASH
FROM dat
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) = 1
```

is the same as:

```
WITH dat AS (
  SELECT id, src, val
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM test
              )

, src AS (
  SELECT id, src, val,
         MD5(
           ARRAY_TO_STRING(
             ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,src,val), ':'
             )
           ) AS CHANGE_HASH
  FROM dat
  WHERE rn = 1
           )
```

and MERGE becomes:

```
MERGE INTO target as tgt 
USING (
        SELECT id, src, val,
             MD5(
               ARRAY_TO_STRING(
                 ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,src,val), ':'
                 )
               ) AS CHANGE_HASH
        FROM dat
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) = 1
      ) AS src
  ON ...
...;
```

Comment: I'll look into qualify but I've massively simplified the transformation in my stored procedure to make a good [mcve] but if I ever use a single CTE to deterministically de-dupe data I'll use `QUALIFY` going forward.

Comment: p.s what's your opinion on handling updates,upserts, inserts & deletes into snowflake using a the above methodlogy? assuming there is nothing like `dbt` involved?

Comment: @Umar.H The idea of checking if data changes to avoid 1:1 updates(no changes) is all right. Alternative to hash computation  `src.CHANGE_HASH != tgt.CHANGE_HASH` could be usage of  row constructor and null-safe operator `(trg.id, trg.src, trg.val) IS DISTINCT FROM (src.id, src.src, src.val)`

Comment: Thanks! I was actually building out a few SDC Type 2s I've just inherited a big clunky (but much used) Snowflake, with no schema (star or otherwise) and lots of shoddy ETL. Looking to get it into shape.